# Python interpreter in http files different from SSH (v2 vs v3)

Tags: python-3.x, interpreter

If I run on my server:

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.2 (default, Mar 10 2019, 18:32:14)
>>> print(sys.executable)
/home2/pvxgnet/python/Python-3.7.2/python
```

---

But when I run from a .py file it only wants to runs with this as the interperter

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n" 
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print "\n" 
print(sys.version)
```

If returns:

```
/usr/bin/python
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]
```

---

If I replace the interpreter w/ this

```
#!/home2/pvxgnet/python/Python-3.7.2/python
```

It returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

---

It looks like its not finding the interpreter. But its finding it when I run from the terminal.

I'm doing something wrong?

*Note: I'm running this script on a bluehost shared server that comes with Python2 installed by default.*

Comment: I imagine it's something to do with your paths. I normally create a virtualenv and then explicitly call python and the scripts with full paths to python and the script. Something like /home2/pvxgnet/python/Python-3.7.2/python /home2/pvxgnet/script.py

Comment: ```which python``` # would also be useful for you.

Comment: which python
`/home2/pvxgnet/python/Python-3.7.2/python`

Comment: but declaring the result as the (#!/home2/pvxgnet/python/Python-3.7.2/python) interpreter returns a server error.

Comment: When upgrading from Python 2 to 3 I also added this to .bashrc `export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-3.7.2/:$PATH`

Comment: I overlooked the http reference. ... What are you using to serve http? Django, Flask, Tornado?

Comment: Nothing as of now, just a simple http call. Which works with Python 2, just not when I change the shebang to the path displayed for the Python 3 interpreter

Comment: also, in the configure file of Python 3 I found this 
# Initializations.
#
ac_default_prefix=/usr/local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189787/discussion-between-pedro-goncalves-and-keith-john-hutchison).